# Unable to debug simple Java application in Eclipse. Cannot connect to VM. AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, debugging, jdwp

When i try to debug a simple application in Eclipse i receive a following error:

*Cannot connect to VM
com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException*

And console provides me with a lonely string:

**FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)**

I have JRE 1.6, JRE 1.7 and JDK 1.7 installed. Tried all of them.

I've seen tons of same topics, but not a single answer helped me to solve my issue. Here they are:

1) Disable Firewall. Doesn't help. I have latest Avast ver. 9.0 at the moment. I'm a bit suspicious about that software, because before updating my Avast i was able to debug in Eclipse. I think it may cause this error, but i do not have direct clues :). I may ping my machine, firewall doesn't block Eclipse traffic, etc.

2) Add strings to hosts file. No reaction.
::1             localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost

3) Changing Network Settings in Java Control Panel to "Direct" connection. Doubtful advice.

Also read that thing: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/FAQ

Can anyone help me to find out what is happening? Or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: did you run eclipse with administrator rights?

Comment: I do run it with admin rights :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avast fixed the issue in the release (build 9.0.2008.177.) it works for some users.

For more info: https://feedback.avast.com/responses/eclipse-debug-functionality-not-working-after-upgrade-to-avast-2014

Comment: You are my savior. On the other hand Avast! support team haven't answered on a single ticket i send to them.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue.  None of the things you tried worked for me either.

Eventually, I uninstalled Avast entirely and the problem went away.  I reinstalled Avast 8.0 and I can still debug, so it must be an issue with the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Avast update has a weird problem where it silently blocks network connections from Java applications, even on localhost, but doesn't close the connection.

I have tried reporting this, but so far have not breached the wall of frustratingly unhelpful tech-support.

Enabling 'Scan traffic from well-known browser processes' fixes this, but shouldn't be needed in the first place.

(I don't have enough reputation to add as a comment yet).

Comment: Actually, i'm wondering why enabling this option should fix the issue? It doesn't work out for me. Isn't TURNING OFF protection do the same job? And it already wasn't working. Btw, about Avast support - did ask them that question same moment i asked it here on stackoverflow - no reaction. What a poor support.

Comment: I imagine that some part of the web shield does funky things for Java connections. It could a half-baked solution for blocking Java based malware. Enabling the option seems to keep protection working for browser processes but disable web shield protection for everything else. I did get replies to my avast ticket.... But they were so unhelpful that I eventually gave up. I'm sorry to hear it didn't work for you. All I can say is that it worked for me.
I basically tried enabling and disabling all the options, and the three things that worked were disabling Avast, disabling the web shield and this